# Clarification on Windows Service Recovery Actions Settings

Tags: windows-services, recovery

I am looking at the recovery actions settings and there are a couple of things that I need clarified.

If I have 0 days as my reset fail count after, and have the following as my actions:

1. Restart the Service - on first failure
2. Restart the Service - on second failure
3. Reboot the Computer - on subsequent failures

Does the fail count get reset on a successful restart of the service?

Does the fail count get reset on the first failure? Hence never having a chance to perform the second or third actions?

On the third successive failure, the computer gets rebooted, the service get started and then fails again; would this reboot the computer again?

Thanks in advance!

Jaime

Answer (score 20):

Setting "Reset fail count after:" to 0 means "reset the fail count to 0 after each failure". This effectively disables both the "second failure" and "subsequent failure" actions and you will always get the "first failure" action.

Comment: that kinda sucks... does this also mean that if i set the reset fail count after to 1 day and it fails for the 3rd time constituting a reboot and then on reboot the service fails again it will do another reboot?

Comment: I think your question is "Does the fail count reset to 0 after a reboot?" - a good one. I have never seen any documentation answering that question, but my guess is that it is reset to 0. That is, the fail count is always "since the OS started". Be sure to test and let me know!

Answer (score 8):

I've tested that fail count on windows XPE. When the service run and I make it fail with "End Process" of the Windows task Manager. I have defined 3 recovery actions:

1. restart service
2. reboot
3. run a program

- On the first "end of process", the service is well restarted. OK.
- On the second "end of process", the compuer is rebooted. OK.
- After the reboot, if I end the process again, it is restarted and if I end it again, the computer is rebooted.

So it seems that this failure counter is reset after every reboot of the computer...

I precise that my fail count is configured to reset after 1 day.