# How to crash to get "Subsequent failures" of Windows Service Recovery to be considered

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

We have a Windows service written in C# that starts basically a Web API on a certain port. The service is configured to be restarted on the first failure and the second failure. The "Subsequent failures" is set to "Take No Action". 
In case this port might be taken the service crashes with an unhandled exception  and in our unhandled exception callback we write dump files to a certain application directory. For whatever reason Windows keeps restarting the service over and over even though it crashed already multiple times. The structure of our service is like this:

```
public class WinService : ServiceBase
{
    private WebApiHostWrapper _apiHost;
    private Thread _workerThread;

    public WinService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceName = "MyService";
        // register handler for writing dumpfiles
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptions.DomainUnhandledException; 
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(InternalStart) { Name = "StartupThread" };
        _workerThread.Start(args);
    }

    private void InternalStart(object args)
    {
        if (null == _service)
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            _apiHost= new WebApiHostWrapper();
            _apiHost.Start((string[])args); // exception here
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (null != _workerThread)
        {
            _apiHost.Dispose();
            _apiHost= null;
            if (!_workerThread.Join(5000))
            {
                _workerThread.Abort();
            }
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            _workerThread = null;
        }
    }
```

In the Windows event log I see 4 entries.

- Service started successfully. (source: MyService)
- Applicatio .... stacktrace etc. (source: .NET Runtime)
- Faulting application name... dll and exe name (source: Application Error)
- Fault bucket, type 0.... (source: Windows Error Reporting)

In a scenario where the port is already in use, this causes the service to crash over and over, flooding the system with dump files. Windows will always restart the service independent from the settings. Is there a special way how to crash in order to get the the "Subsequent Failures" to be considered and NOT to restart the service?

Comment: Not sure how to avoid subsequent restarts tbh. Haven't made such a test myself but to give you an idea, on startup of your app you can try to find pid of app that uses port X and can send a kill sign for that pid maybe? So that your app can actually start up?

Comment: The reserved ports are only one of many things that might happen during the startup of the application. In theory we could also do a clean stop when we detect an error during startup as well but that's not what we want to achieve. We want to have dump files for analysis what happened since it might be a real bug that caused the unexpected stop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that caused only the "First failure" to be executed. We had the "Reset fail count after" set to 0 days. After setting this value to 1 the service crashed 2 times and then was not restarted anymore.

Sources:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3db76753-4607-4a20-97a0-790c73e379cc/the-actions-after-system-service-failure?forum=winserver8gen

[Clarification on Windows Service Recovery Actions Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405178/clarification-on-windows-service-recovery-actions-settings)

http://www.happysysadm.com/2011/12/understanding-windows-services-recovery.html